# c programming question on reinterpret_cast

Tags: c, pointers, byte, reinterpret-cast

What is the reinterpret_cast of (char) doing here?

```c
 unsigned int aNumber = 258; // 4 bytes in allocated memory [02][01][00][00]
 printf("\n is printing out the first byte %02i",(char)aNumber); // Outputs the first byte[02]
```

Why am i getting out the first byte without pointing to it? such as (char*)&aNumber

is the %02i doing this = (char)*&aNumber

or is the reinterpret_cast of (char) cutting out the rest 3 bytes since it is a char it only allocate one byte of them 4 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `reinterpret_cast` is a C++ operator.  What you've shown is not that but a C-style cast.

The cast is converting a value of type `unsigned int` to a value of type `char`.  Conversion of an out-of-range value is implementation defined, but in most implementations you're likely to come across, this is implemented as reinterpreting the lower order bytes as the converted value.

In this particular case, the low order byte of `aNumber` has the value 0x02, so that's what the result is when casted to a `char`.

Comment: so the  C-style cast of char is basically keeping the first byte only, since char(1 byte) can not store the other rest 3 bytes. right?

Comment: Re "*Conversion of an out-of-range value is implementation defined*", While true if `char` is signed, this is not true if `char` is unsigned. In that case, *the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.* (C17 6.3.1.3.2)

Comment: Note that the least significant byte ("low order byte") is not necessarily the *first* byte.

Comment: @dn70a, Re "*so the C-style cast of char is basically keeping the first byte only*", No. Like the answer says, this may be equivalent to what happens for you, but that's hardly what the cast does.

Comment: i am not getting it :(
so ... (unsigned char)aNumber; // could end up showing  different result as is not a guarantee that it will keep the first byte?

Comment: @dn70a, Re "*i am not getting it*", There's a wide range of legal results, and getting the first byte is just one of them.

Comment: @dn70a The cast is keeping the *least significant byte*.  On a little endian system like yours apparently is, it happens to be the first byte.  On a big endian system, which stores the most significant byte first, it happens to be the last byte.

Comment: @dbush ahh ok i thin k i get it now ,
 so if the bytes where to be  [22][88][01][02] <--- in this case the third byte would be printed out since it is the lowest of the rest of the bytes right?

Comment: @dn70a No, on your system casting from an `int` to a `char` will always give you the first byte.  Your system stores the `int` value 0x01020304 as 0x04 0x03 0x02 0x01 (little endian).  Some other system may store the same value as 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 (big endian).  But on both systems `(char)0x01020304` would give you 0x04 because that is the value of the least significant byte, regardless of how a particular system orders the bytes.

Comment: @dbush aah Ok.. so i might get it now . does this also Applies for the pointers? a pointer always points at the first byte in the address where the values are store, as in the big endian will the pointer point to the last byte?

Comment: @dn70a No, a pointer points to the first byte of an object.

Comment: I suggest “reinterpreting the lower order bytes as the converted value” → “reinterpreting the lower order bytes in the destination type”.